# Pointer to type within a macro, C

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I've run into a problem when attempting to express the pointer to a type within a macro.

Take this simple example.

```
#define INDEX_OF_DATA(data, type, index) \
    ((type *)data)[index]
```

This works:

```
INDEX_OF_DATA(buffer, float, 3);
```

Where this fails:

```
INDEX_OF_DATA(buffer, float[2], 3);
```

Because the cast should be `(float(*)[2])`.

Is there a way to express *"the pointer of a `type`"*, ...without using `typeof`? (which isn't standard C).

---

Note, there are of course other ways to make this specific example work. cast to char and offset by `sizeof(type) * index` for example. But am interested in a way to express `pointer to type` in C.

Comment: I don't think this is possible without extensions, but I'll be curious to know if anyone has a better idea.

Comment: c++ has better solution with type inference, but with C your choice is next to none

Answer (score 4):

Doing heavily complicated stuff with C types may be a fun sport, but it's extremely confusing in real code.

To avoid wrecking their heads over complicated pointer expressions too much, people often use `typedef`!

If you `typedef` all the types that you expect to use with this macro of yours, you won't have any problems. Observe:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#define INDEX_OF_DATA(data, type, index) \
    ((type *)data)[index]


int main(void) {
    float (*buffer)[2] = malloc(4 * sizeof(float[2]));

    typedef float t_f2arr[2];

    INDEX_OF_DATA(buffer, t_f2arr, 3)[0] = 1.1f;

    return 0;
}
```

This does exactly what you intended!

Comment: >main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
>main.cpp:17:32: error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘float (*)[2]’ [-fpermissive]
>     float (*buffer)[2] = malloc(4 * sizeof(float[2]));

Comment: @Alper91 this is a C question, not a C++ question. In C++ using malloc without a typecast is illegal (as there's no implicit conversion from a `void*` to other pointer types), so in C++ you would need to do `(float (*)[2])malloc(...)` or move up the typedef and do `(t_f2arr*)malloc(...)`

Answer (score 1):

If we want to preserve the original macro, we can use this trick:

```
#define INDEX_OF_DATA(data, type, index) ((type*)data)[index]

struct mystruct { float f[2]; };
mystruct* p = &INDEX_OF_DATA(buffer, mystruct, 3);
```

Unfortunately this solution could be affected by struct padding so it's better to check:

```
static_assert(sizeof(mystruct) == sizeof(float (*)[2]), "padding found");
```

Comment: This won't even compile in C

Comment: @texasbruce Yes, you are right. Even if my solution is not perfect, it can possibly stimulate other and better solutions.